# foreach over object array not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4

I'm using Charts,js by devex (find the link to the documentation by clicking  [here](http://chartjs.devexpress.com/Documentation/Tutorial/Configure_Charts?version=13_2)). I'm also using the Laravel framework. I need to generate some JQuery on the server side to output the graphs I want. I am passing `$json_micromarket_participants` which is an **array of objects** (rows from database query) that are **json_encoded** in my controller. Each object has a `Home_name` and `Average_Occupancy` property.

For some reason my foreach loop doesn't work, i.e. I get the following error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

My question is twofold:
 1. Why doesn't it work?
 2. Would this code work anyway to generate name
    and value pairs in jquery?

Code:

```
 @section('content')

<script type="text/javascript">

    var chartDataSource = {{ $json_micromarket_participants }};


    $(function () {
        $("#chartContainer").dxChart({dataSource: chartDataSource,
        commonSeriesSettings:{argumentField: 'Home_name'},

        series: [
        @foreach($json_micromarket_participants as $micromarket_participant)
            {
            name:       '{{$micromarket_participant->Home_name}}',            
            valueField: '{{$micromarket_participant->Average_Occupancy}}'
            },
        @endforeach
        ]

        });
    })
</script>

<div id="chartContainer" style="max-width:700px; height:300px;"></div>

 @stop
```

---

In the controller, here's how $json_micromarket_participants is set. It's all fine on that side I think...

```
    $micromarket_participants       = DB::table('homes')
                                -> select(array('*', DB::raw('SQRT(POW('.$Eastings.' - `Eastings`,2) + POW('.$Northings.' - `Northings`,2)) AS distance')))
                                -> having('distance', '<', $micromarket_size)
                                -> get();


$json_micromarket_participants = json_encode($micromarket_participants);
```

Comment: Is `$json_micromarket_participants` being set in the controller and then passed to the view? Can we see where it is being set?

Comment: @watcher Done add it as an edit

Comment: Try dumping the `$json_micromarket_participants` to the output screen and you could easily identify the error

Comment: @AnoXP I don't see what you mean... I already vardumped it but I know the objects have the properties I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because you have encoded $micromarket_participants into json, making it a string, not an array.

I think $micromarket_participants is the array of objects in this case, so you should just use this in your view:

```
@foreach($micromarket_participants as $micromarket_participant)
```

Comment: Interesting, however if I don't `Json_encode` I get a array to string conversion error when I echo it to set it equal to `var ChartDataSource`

Comment: If you would like the full data for the `ChartDataSource`, you can go ahead and use  json_encode for that. For the creation of the name value pair, however, you should just iterate through the original array.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are calling `json_encode` on the `$micromarket_participants` object, which I don't think that will return what you want.  Instead, try just calling the `toJson` method on the returned collection:

```
$json_micromarket_participants = $micromarket_participants->toJson();
```

Comment: interesting... it now gives me the following error:

Call to a member function toJson() on a non-object